# BW concentration of cell boundaries

Tags: matlab, classification, cell, shapes

I am trying to find the borders of the cell concentration in black and white image. I draw more or less what i am trying to achieve. The borders can be smoothed, it doesnt have to be exatch. But anyhow outliers should be excluded. Thats why i didnt want to take the lowest points.Can you suggest any ideas ? I have put the raw image as example as attached.
[BW Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WA50.png)
[image: boundary]

Answer (score 0):

Tried to give it a shot using some rudimentary image-processing concepts. Didn't get the best results but possibly this might serve as a starting point. I'd imagine they're better methods and models that can be used. I also had to crop the left side of the original image with the white vertical line.

Used:

• Mean filters

• Windowing functions

• Sobel filters

[image: Cell Boundary Detection]

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
File_Name = "Cell_Image.png";
Image = imread(File_Name);
Greyscale_Image = rgb2gray(Image);

Denoised_Image = filter2(fspecial('average',45),Greyscale_Image)/255;
Edge_Image = edge(Denoised_Image,'sobel');

[Image_Height,Image_Width,Depth] = size(Image);

Max_Image = zeros(Image_Height,Image_Width);
Index_Bank = zeros(1,Image_Width);

for Column_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Width

    Indicies = find(Edge_Image(:,Column_Scanner));
    Index = max(Indicies,[],'all');
%     Max_Image(Index+1,Column_Scanner) = 1;
    if sum(Index) > 0
    Index_Bank(1,Column_Scanner) = Index;
    end
end

windowSize = 20; 
b = (1/windowSize)*ones(1,windowSize);
a = 0.95;
Max_Data = filter(b,a,Index_Bank);
Max_Data = round(Max_Data);


for Column_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Width
    Image(Max_Data(1,Column_Scanner),Column_Scanner,1) = 255;
end


imshow(Image);
```